# Facebook iFrames and XFS risks

Tags: security, iframe, xss, facebook-iframe, iframe-app

We want to do a Facebook app for our brand page, where a form will be brought in from a secure domain that we own. But our finance department seems unwilling to allow this because of "cross frame scripting" attacks that are possible with iFrames.

Many big companies have apps inside FB and are collecting user data. I doubt FB would allow any code that would be insecure in this manner. I am looking for any site that talks about how FB manages such risks. What can we do to manage this risk on our end? Isn't it true that if our content is coming from our own secure server, then FB just happens to be the *place* where we do out stuff, but the actual security lays with us?

Would welcome any thoughts to counter our finance department's reservations, or even pointers to read up on this subject in detail. FB's own help is sparse on this matter.

Thanks!

Comment: @Sean Kinsey that is incorrect.  This is a method of exploiting XSS.

Comment: @Rook The page you refer to is mostly mentioning CSRF and XSS, with iframes simply being a method for having the pages loaded. Sure, it's defined by OWASP as such, so I get your point.

Answer (score 1):

[Cross-frame scripting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross_Frame_Scripting) is a method of exploiting a Cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerability.  If your web application has been tested and found to be immune to XSS vulnerabilities then Cross-frame scripting is not a concern.

You might want to read about the [Same Origin Policy and how it treats iframes](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Origin_inheritance_rules).  As a side note,  XSS is useful to attackers because it allows them to bypass the Same Origin Policy.

With a site that allows iframe'd content you have to worry about [clickjacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking).  if you are unfamiliar with extremely common web application vulnerability like XSS,  make sure to read the OWASP top 10.

Comment: As for the clickjacking (and assuming that Facebook itself will not have implemented such a thing or is vulnerable to XSS to insert code for it), an `X-Frame-Options` header limiting the domains which are _allowed_ to embed the APP in an iframe is a good additional counter measure.

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't it true that if our content is coming from our own secure server, then FB just happens to be the place where we do ou[r] stuff, but the actual security lays with us?

Yes, pretty much.

So if your concern is mainly that you get no bogus input data, then look at Facebook’s measures to confirm the genuineness of a client pretending to be a Facebook user, e.g. the `signed_request`. And hire expert knowledge against (perceived) web threats such as *“cross frame scripting attacks”* and whatever actual thing or buzzword might get thrown at you; or/and have your end result checked/certified by an organization specializing in this.

If the concern is about what a hacker taking control over the app/your app’s server might be able to do with the stored client input data – well that’s a case for a dedicated web server running nothing but your app, located in your company’s [DMZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_%28computing%29). That app server will only have write access to the data on your LAN data server – for example by making all it’s database queries using an account with only `INSERT` privilege granted.

---

Btw., in what kind of company is the *Finance* Dept. the sovereignty on matters of (web) security? Should we be concerned if we were customers …? ;-)